# How to enable hardware acceleration in Azure VM NV6 Windows 10

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I tried to run SketchUp 2017 in my Azure VM NV6 Windows 10 but failed.
[SketchUp failure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU3K0.png)

Then I downloaded the driver from nvidia official website http: //www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/111405/en-us and tried to install it but failed again.
[Nvidia driver installation failure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynphX.png)

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem.

The Nvidia driver doesn't install because I "Eject Display Controller" from the bottom-right tray. Without the ejection, I can install the driver and then SketchUp works.